# ERC721 Converter?

Tags: erc20, erc721, converter

I've heard that Cardano will be releasing an ERC20 converter. I'm wondering if there are plans for the converter to work with ERC721 tokens as well.
I'm interested in how to make a new NFT token program interoperable between ETH and ADA.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There have not been any plans announced to create an ERC721 converter.  ERC-721 defines some functions with compliance to ERC-20. This makes it *easier* for existing wallets to display simple token information.  However, they have differing capabilities and attributes.

The Cardano solution for the foreseeable future seems to be issuance of a native token on the Cardano blockchain.

It is likely that the value of creating an ERC721 converter is outweighed by the work required.